# Display custom content for specific product tags in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I use the below to add custom html or a text in WooCommerce single product pages, after short description:

```
function my_content( $content ) {
    $content .= '<div class="custom_content">Custom content!</div>';

    return $content;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'my_content', 10, 2);
```

How to restrict this on product pages that contain a specific product tag *(not a product category)*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`has_term()` WordPress conditional function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/), to restrict your custom content to be displayed only for products that have specific product tag(s) as follows *(defining below in the function your product tag(s) term(s))*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'my_content', 10, 2);
function my_content( $content ) {
    // Here define your specific product tag terms (can be Ids, slugs or names)
    $product_tags = array( 'Garden', 'Kitchen' );

    if( has_term( $product_tags, 'product_tag', get_the_ID() ) ) {
        $content .= '<div class="custom_content">' . __("Custom text!", "") . '</div>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Hi again, unfortunately the text appears even on category pages that are listing products containing that tag :( . Is there a way I can limit it to product page only ?

Comment: @ClawDuda use: `if( is_product() && has_term( $product_tags, 'product_tag', get_the_ID() ) ) {`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec

are u the creator of woocommerce ? how can your solution works like a charm always!

Comment: `__("Custom text!", "") ` whats the purpose of double underscore here? and the latter ""

Comment: It's work for me, Thanks for the answers.